# Display current time in Live Tile?

Tags: 8.0, tiles

I would like to add a Live Tile to display the current time (only minutes accuracy).

Is there a tile for the builtin clock? Is there an app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Developers may only update Live Tiles every half hour. Being an OEM partner HTC is the only one being able to offer a clock where the tile can update every Minute. But as Maura said, this is currently exclusive to the 8X (and 8S I guess).

Answer (score 2):

Note: For Windows Phone 8

There are multiple clock apps, both analog and digital, if you check the store. A good (free) one is called "World Clock" from Live Apps - you can create one or more live tile clocks.

The HTC 8x has an in-the-box time tile, by the way but it's currently unique to the 8x.

Comment: Appreciated! Does it have a Live Tile? Will it update more often than half an hour?